# Rails LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, join

Let's say i have the following models:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :shifts    
end

class Shift < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :employee
end
```

In my controller I want to load all employees including their shifts in a certain date range.
But I also want to include employees without any shifts in that range.

In my controller I tried:

```
@employees.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN shifts ON employees.id = shifts.employee_id").where('shifts.starts_at BETWEEN ? and ?', weekBegin, weekEnd).to_json(:include => :shifts)
```

But this still just returns the employees with shifts in that date range. I also want to return employees with no shifts in that date range.

How does such a query work?

Answer (score 4):

You should include conditions on the shifts start time into the join statement:

```
@employees.joins("
     LEFT OUTER JOIN shifts 
     ON employees.id = shifts.employee_id
     AND shifts.starts_at 
         BETWEEN #{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(weekBegin)} 
             AND #{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize(weekEnd)}
").to_json(:include => :shifts)
```

Comment: Thanks looks good. The only problem is that it loads all shifts now. Not only the ones in the date range but all.

Comment: That's strange. Can you check what SQL query is generated in the result?

Comment: SELECT "employees".* FROM "employees" LEFT OUTER JOIN shifts 
 ON employees.id = shifts.employee_id
 AND shifts.starts_at 
 BETWEEN '2012-07-09 00:00:00.000000' 
 AND '2012-07-15 23:59:59.999999' WHERE "employees"."company_id" = 1 ORDER BY lastname asc, firstname asc LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0

Comment: And then 4 more: 
Shift Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "shifts".* FROM "shifts" WHERE "shifts"."employee_id" = 3
  Shift Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "shifts".* FROM "shifts" WHERE "shifts"."employee_id" = 4
  Shift Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "shifts".* FROM "shifts" WHERE "shifts"."employee_id" = 2
  Shift Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "shifts".* FROM "shifts" WHERE "shifts"."employee_id" = 1

Comment: Hm, the time format in the `BETWEEN` part looks suspicious. What DB are you using and did you get the same time format in the `WHERE` clause with your original query? Otherwise, the generated query looks good.

Comment: I use postgresql. I tried the first query in my db management tool and it didn't work. But not because of the time formats. SELECT "employees".* has to be SELECT *

Comment: Ah, crap. You can add `.select('*')`, but it won't help. The problem is that ActiveRecord joins return all columns of the joined tables in a single object. On the other hand `to_json(:include => :shifts)` will simply ask your `employee` object for `shifts` association that will be queried from the DB. Can't think of any elegant solution at the moment.

Comment: Yes tried out .select("*"), too. Seems some other people have the same problem. I might use :method instead of :include and define my own function. NOt very elegant because it won't be called shifts anymore but ok. Thanks for your help

Comment: Yeah, I though about `:method` option, but afaik it doesn't allow to specify method parameters, so you can't pass arbitrary time range.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do that

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN shifts ON employees.id = shifts.employee_id AND shifts.starts_at BETWEEN weekBegin and weekEnd
```